# "Flags for <username>" header has a minor UI layout issue in the flagging history view

Tags: bug, flags, design

If I open my flagging history view I see the posts and comments I flagged and some summary. It looks like this:

[image: screenshot for the flagging history]

The header states "Flags for" and the username. Screenshot:

[image: screenshot for the flagging history header]

My username 'Robert F.' has a space in it and 8 character long. The UI wraps the text and puts the second part of the username under the line separating the header from the content.

Although it's really a minor thing I think it's not intended that way, hence this post.

I used the site in a full-screen browser on a 1920x1200 monitor when I experienced the issue.